# Cloudformation `StartingPositionTimestamp` for Lambda/Kinesis event source mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I'm looking to connect a Kinesis stream to a Lambda function via event source mapping, want to set the `StartingPosition` value to `AT_TIMESTAMP` -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-startingposition

So now I'm looking to set the actual timestamp for that starting position.

If I look at the AWS CLI there seems to be a parameter for it (`--starting-position-timestamp`) -

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping help
```

```
SYNOPSIS
            create-event-source-mapping
          --event-source-arn <value>
          --function-name <value>
          [--enabled | --no-enabled]
          [--batch-size <value>]
          [--starting-position <value>]
          [--starting-position-timestamp <value>]
          [--cli-input-json <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

and if I look at `boto3` there is a `StartingPositionTimestamp` parameter -

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping

```
response = client.create_event_source_mapping(
    EventSourceArn='string',
    FunctionName='string',
    Enabled=True|False,
    BatchSize=123,
    StartingPosition='TRIM_HORIZON'|'LATEST'|'AT_TIMESTAMP',
    StartingPositionTimestamp=datetime(2015, 1, 1)
)
```

but I can't find any such `StartingPositionTimestamp` parameter in the `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` docs -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html

So how do I set Kinesis starting position timestamp via Cloudformation ?

Comment: The question is why do you want to start at a specific timestamp? In most of the cases `LATEST` or `TRIM_HORIZON` are enough since Kinesis only stores your events for a certain period (due to the `retention period`). Also, I have the feeling that CloudFormation does not support to set the `StartingPositionTimestamp` at all in this case (but I have no evidence for that).

Comment: hmm okay I need to read more about `TRIM_HORIZON` then. But why have `AT_TIMESTAMP` if you can't specify a timestamp ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a miss when the feature was originally launched, but it's correctly supported now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-startingpositiontimestamp

Answer (score -2):

Great question, and I'm stuck with this myself. Not just *"How do I specify the timestamp in the CloudFormation template?"*, but obviously *"How do I update the timestamp that the EventSourceMapping uses?"*

This isn't really a static property so doesn't lend itself to CloudFormation.

I'm guessing here, but maybe you should update the timestamp as part of your process. Bootstrap your app by setting timestamp as epoch, and then after reading your stream set it to the timestamp of the last processed element.

Comment: I think I just ended up using LATEST :-/